# Replace string with newline and add text

Tags: bash, sed, scripting

This one is probably easy, but cant figure it out, I want to replace `<BR>` with newline and add `https://` behind `example.com`

**example:**

```
https://www.google.com<BR>example.com
```

**would become:**

```
https://www.google.com
https://example.com
```

I tried using `sed` but probably messed up.

```
sed 's/<BR>/\n/g'
```

which replaces `<BR>` with newline, but cant figure out how to add `https://`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use alternative delimiters

```
sed 's=<BR>=\nhttps://='
```

or backslash the slashes

```
sed 's/<BR>/\nhttps:\/\//'
```